# How to time how long a Python program takes to run?

Tags: python, time

Is there a simple way to time a Python program's execution?

clarification: Entire programs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html):

> This module provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code. It has both command line as well as callable interfaces. It avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times.

You'll need a python statement in a string; if you have a main function in your code, you could use it like this:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> timer = Timer('main()', 'from yourmodule import main')
>>> print timer.timeit()
```

The second string provides the setup, the environment for the first statement to be timed in. The second part is not being timed, and is intended for setting the stage as it were. The first string is then run through it's paces; by default a million times, to get accurate timings.

If you need more detail as to where things are slow, use one of the [`python profilers`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html):

> A profiler is a program that describes the run time performance of a program, providing a variety of statistics.

The easiest way to run this is by using the `cProfile` module from the command line:

```bash
$ python -m cProfile yourprogram.py
```

Comment: I looked at the link and found it a little confusing. Is there an easy script that shows how to use this?

Comment: `timeit` is for micro-benchmarks: tiny program snippets, not whole programs.

Comment: If all you want to know if it is fast or slow, `timeit` is fine. If you need to know *where* it is slow in a larger program, you need to profile.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not understand the arguments of Timer. Let's say I am putting my main program, def myProg(), in the script. At the very bottom, outside of the myProg() function, what would I put in the timer arguments?

Comment: `Timer('myProg()', 'from __main__ import myProg')` should do it.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from running a million times? My program takes longer than a second and that means it'd take many days to finish

Comment: Call `.timeit()` with a lower number; so `.timeit(10)` will run it 10 times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again, `timeit` is the wrong tool here. Even ten times is not necessary for timing a 1-second-run (for a fair benchmark amongst multiple options, yes, but not for getting an idea of how long a single program takes). The repetition is only built into `timeit` because it's for microbenchmarks and OS scheduling can have *huge* impact on snippets that take less than a microsecond or less to run, and it does not hurt to spend half a second (rather than finish instantly) for far more accurate results.

Comment: @delnan: sure, but through this all the OP has not given us the underlying usecase, so all I can do is help understand the tools for whatever he wants to use it.

Comment: Well, I thought it's pretty clear an entire program is in question even with the initial version of the question. Since then, it has been edited to explicitly state that (and you edited afterwards, without dropping the `timeit` approach). But now your answer is accepted, so it's somewhat moot.

Comment: @delnan Most of my programs are around a second or less than a second in terms of their speeds, so accuracy does matter here. Are you saying timeit is still not appropriate here? What would you recommend?

Comment: @user1435323 I'd say it's not worth the hassle. Just use an OS command to time the entire program from start to finish (like `time`, as Steven Rumbalski suggested, and I believe Powershell has an equivalent). It's more accurate as it includes Python startup and module-level code (imports, definitions, etc.) and if you want to account for differences due to OS scheduling, you can still run it three times.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use built-in [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Also you might want to measure function's running time by using following simple decorator:

```
import time
def myprof(func):
    def wrapping_fun(*args):
        start = time.clock()
        result = func(*args)
        end = time.clock()
        print 'Run time of %s is %4.2fs' % (func.__name__, (end - start))
        return result
    return wrapping_fun
```

Usage:

```
@myprof
def myfun():
    # function body
```

Comment: That's a pretty poor profiling function. I wouldn't rely on it for anything worth benchmarking/profiling in the first place.

Comment: Numerous reasons, most of which reduce to "none of us is smart enough to do this well off-hand". For starters, `time.clock` is not the most precise clock on all platforms (cf. `default_clock()` defined by `timetit`), and the output is very limited (intermingled with program output, need to collect and parse by hand). Minor issues include not accounting for exceptions and not using `functools.wrap`.

Comment: @delnan: You're absolutely right, it's definitely not universal tool for profiling, but sometimes I use it as a snippet.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Linux/Unix/POSIX-combatible platform just use [`time`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=time). This way you won't interfere with you script and won't slow it down with unnecessarily detailed (for you) profiling. Naturally, you can use it for pretty much anything, not just Python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

For snippets use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.

For entire programs use the  [`cProfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-pstats) module.

Answer (score 2):

Use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

```
>>> import timeit  
>>> t = timeit.Timer(stmt="lst = ['c'] * 100")  
>>> print t.timeit()  
1.10580182076  
>>> t = timeit.Timer(stmt="lst = ['c' for x in xrange(100)]")  
>>> print t.timeit()  
7.66900897026
```